# how to validate form in a order codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I would like to validate my login form like Google does.

First check username then check password; If both are empty then there is only an error on the username box.

In CodeInginter, if both are empty it prints each field is required messages.

Can we mimic this functionality easily with CodeIgnightor?

Comment: Hi can you please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817/can-we-prevent-some-of-the-low-quality-questions-from-entering-our-system - thanks! I approved the edit and the sms short hand isn't suited to this site...

Comment: sorry about sms typing, my mistake.

Comment: I typically do the 'google style' validation client side, and ultimately validate both server side. The client side validation should _normally_ prevent submission if one or the other is missing, which makes messages complaining about both extremely rare. This eliminates a lot of cruft in your controller as well.

Comment: yes, I think that's something I missed.thanks Tim

Comment: but is there way to override CI methode?

Comment: when It is a loging form, I dont like to depend on javascript as this is directly causes to security of the site.

Answer (score 0):

you need to research before you post some question. These kind of information available in codeIgniter user guide. Any way i am providing simple example.

View file: login.php

```
   <form action="<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/controller_name/post_login" method="post" >
                    <p>
                        <label>Email:</label> <?php echo form_error('email'); ?><br />
                        <input type="text" class="text" name="email" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <label>Password:</label> <?php echo form_error('passwd'); ?><br />
                        <input type="password" name="passwd" class="text" value="" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <input type="submit"  class="submit" value="Login" />                               

                    </p>
    </form>
```

Controller function which is written in controller file..........

```
 public function post_login()
    {

        $error_in_validation=set_form_validation($this->config->item('login_form'));

        if($error_in_validation){
            show_form_validation_error('controller_file_name/login');
        }
        else
        {
            $email=$this->input->post('email');
            $passwd=$this->input->post('passwd');
            $ret=$this->model_file_name->user_login($email, $passwd);

            if($ret == NULL){

                $model=array();
                $model['error_msg']=$this->config->item('login_form_error_code_1');;
                $this->load->view('controller_file_name/login',$model);             
            } else {
                redirect("ro_manager/home");
            }

        }

    }
```

After this you need to create you need to create a file name called form_validation in config folder. In that you need to write the validation rules as per user guide.

```
     $config['login_form'] = array (
                        array 
                        (
                            'key' => 'email', 
                            'value' => 'Email',
                            'rule' => 'trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean'
                        ),
                        array
                        (
                            'key' => 'passwd', 
                            'value' => 'Password',
                            'rule' => 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|xss_clean'
                        )
                      );
```

Comment: ok, I think you misunderstand me. I can show error messages using CI api. Even, in your form is submitted with empty strings then we get 2 error messages. I dont need that, only to show username is empty.

Comment: I think you can understand me if you check google loging validtion

Answer (score 0):

Try like this way

```
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){

    $this->load->view('myform');

   }else{
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'required');
     if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
       $this->load->view('myform');
     }
     $this->load->view('formsuccess');
   }
```

Comment: I mean , using CI api, is there a way to override the form_error() method. I can handle it from server side. thanks.

Comment: Yes you can by creating your custom library http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/creating_libraries.html